# adding jquery datepicker function to ajax live table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html) to add a table my users can edit live. Works great! I have a field that is a date that needs to be able to edit. I want to add the jquery "[datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)" function with one of the fields.

here is my javascript

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".edit_tr").click(function()
    {
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    $("#date_"+ID).hide();
    $("#starttime_"+ID).hide();
    $("#endtime_"+ID).hide();
    $("#date_input_"+ID).show();
    $("#starttime_input_"+ID).show();
    $("#endtime_input_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function()
    {
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    var date=$("#date_input_"+ID).val();
    var start=$("#starttime_input_"+ID).val();
    var end=$("#endtime_input_"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&date='+ date +'&starttime='+start+'&endtime='+end;
    $("#date_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />');


    if(date.length && starttime.length && endtime.length>0)
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

    $("#date_"+ID).html(date);
    $("#starttime_"+ID).html(starttime);
    $("#endtime_"+ID).html(endtime);
    }
    });
    }
    else
    {
    alert('Enter something.');
    }
    });
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
    {
    return false
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function()
    {
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".text").show();
    });

    });
    ///////CALLING DATEPICKER FUNCTION///////
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

and the date field

```
<td width="10%" class="edit_td">
<span id="date_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo date("m/d/y",strtotime($date)); ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" class="editbox" id="date_input_<?php echo $id;?>" />
</td>
```

I tried adding the datepicker to the id like this "date_input_ datepicker" but it just breaks and does nothing. Any help?

Comment: You could try doing the datepicker on a class instead of an id. But it might still need a refresh of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `datepicker` id in there so your function call can't find the place to add the picker.

You need to add datepicker to an input field, all your input fields are have class editbox so you can add datepicker to them all like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".editbox" ).datepicker();
});
```

That should work. If only some inputs are dates then define those ones with an extra class and then use that:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" class="editbox datebox" id="date_input_<?php echo $id;?>" />
```

and then

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datebox" ).datepicker();
});
```

I've checked and datepicker behaves sensibly when it's associated element is hidden / revealed. However there may be cases where it does not.

A different solution that may be more flexible is to initialize the datepicker in the `click` subroutine and use the `destroy()` method when the input field disappears.

To do this you'd start the datepicker as you're revealing the input field, so in the `click` function you could add a line like:

```
$("#date_input_"+ID).datepicker();
```

(probably before or after the .show() call for `#date_input_`). Ideally you should store the ID of the active element so you can destroy the datepicker nicely, but you could just go overkill change the second `mouseup` function to destroy any datepickers on `editbox` elements:

```
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".editbox").datepicker('destroy'); 
    $(".text").show();
});
```

I've done some brief tests on both methods and they seem to do what you want.